# Fill dropdown list with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have SQLite table with columns id and name. I return array of those rows like json from autocomplete.php page. How to fill select with options ( drop down list ) with this json using jquery and JavaScript ? I am new to JavaScript and JQuery, I googled but didn't find how. In ASP.NET this is easy but here I don't know. Would somebody help ?

This is example of my JSON, can be much longer.

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "test"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "test"
    }
]
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful / resolve your issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

HTML:

```
<select id="sel">

</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    var data = [
        {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "test1"},
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "test2"}
    ];
    $.each(data, function(i, option) {
        $('#sel').append($('<option/>').attr("value", option.id).text(option.name));
    });
})
```

Here's a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/ms2Ma/

Comment: what would that look like without the JQuery syntax ? I don't understand what `$('<option/>')` is or does

Answer (score 4):

Try this, This will give you an option to have any number of dropdown boxes and JSON nodes to configure dropdown boxes.

You need to follow few steps:

- Create an array of dropdown boxes.(e.g. if you have to configure a phone then you should be using dropdown of color, memory etc.)
- Create a JSON object as it is created in code. Dont change the configurable items name which starts with "level1" and end with any number of nodes, As it has to be sync with the index of items of array you are creating in the first place.

Here is the data:

```
var Dropdowns = ["Model", "Color", "Memory","design","covers","music"];
var Data ={"phones":[
  {
     "oid":":000000F0:00000458:",
     "level1":"3G",
     "level2":"white",
     "level3":"16GB",
     "level4":"slim",
     "level5":"Back cover",
     "level6":"headphone",
     "price":"£568.63",
     "addToCart":"#Cart1"
  },
  {
     "oid":":000000F0:000003DA:",
     "level1":"3G",
     "level2":"black",
     "level3":"16GB",
     "level4":"slim",
     "level5":"Flip cover",
     "level6":"headphone",
     "price":"£615.79",
     "addToCart":"#Cart7"
  }]};
```

See the full working code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/raju_sumit/681ppgq0/5/

Answer (score 2):

**A pure Javascript solution:** this snippet shows how to populate a dropdown select from JSON data (using `id` as value and `name` as text.

The code creates a new [`Option` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) for each item in the JSON data and appends it to the select element with [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is used in place of a `for` loop.

```js
let data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "name_1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "name_2"
  }
];

var selectElement = document.getElementById('mySelect');

data.map(item => mySelect.appendChild(new Option(item.name, item.id)).cloneNode(true));
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="alert(this.value)"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

Javascript:

```
$.getJSON("/array.json",
  function (json) {
      $.each(json,
      function (key, value) {
      $("#id-select").append("<option value='" + value.c + "'>" + value.d + "</option>");
      });
});
```

Comment: please explain how this answer the question