# How to populate a dropdown list with a locally stored JSON file

Tags: php, jquery, json, laravel, dropdown

Below is my JSON File , I am using Laravel and also i'm wondering where is the correct practice to store my json file.

```
{
    "people": [
      "john",
      "jim",
      "mark"
     ]
}
```

What I am currently looking to achieve is populate a dropdown list as shown below also.

```
<form method="POST" action="/Update">
@csrf 
     <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown" onchange="this.form.submit()">
     </select>
</form>
```

Here is my jquery script how I have tried doing it however i'm getting a 404 HTTP error. Also as I noted above where do you think I should store the json file locally within my project folder.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var people = "storage/people.json";

        $.getJSON(people, function (data) {
            $.each(people,function(iIndex, sElement) {
      $('#dropdown').append('<option>' + sElement + '</option>');
   });
});
});
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill dropdown list with json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532791/fill-dropdown-list-with-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel, page contents such as scripts, styles, images, etc. are usually stored in the `public` folder. So I would suggest you store your JSON file in the 'public' folder.

Testing your code gave some errors and a quick fix to your code is provided below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var people = "/document/people.json";

        $.getJSON(people, function (data) {
            data.people.forEach(function(value, index){
                $('#dropdown').append('<option>' + value + '</option>');
            });
        });
});
```

This adjustment to your jquery code works and the placement of the json file is `public/document/people.json`

Answer (score 0):

Create a symlink from your public to your storage

```
ln -s storage/app/public public/storage
```

and use `asset('storage/your.json')`

**Laravel routes.php**

```
Route::get('/json/people', 'JsonController@people')->name('json.people');
```

**Run artisan command in your laravel root project**

```
php artisan make:controller JsonController
```

**In your JsonController**

Create a method called `people`

```
public function people(Request $request)
{
    $data = file_get_contents(asset('storage/your.json'));
    return response()->json(['data'=> $data]);
}
```

Change your Jquery for `Ajax` request

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/json/people",
  data: {"_token": //you need to add a CSRF Token to your form. Fetch it via JQuery to add it here and send with your Ajax}
}).done(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
    // once you confirm your JSON data is here, do what you wish to achieve! :)
});
```

As for the CSRF, if you prefer, you can add it as a meta tag and use that in your Ajax as stated below:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Then before your Ajax call, add a setup for your Ajax:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

If you decide to use the Meta Tag approach for the CSRF then you can scrap out the `data`variable from your Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/json/people"
    }).done(function(data) {
         console.log(data);
        // once you confirm your JSON data is here, do what you wish to achieve! :)
    });
```

Comment: I shall try this as soon as I can, also in the people method it states return response()->json(['data'=> ]); shouldn't after data=> have a variable after it or is meant to be like that?

Comment: Apologies, forgot to add the variable there :3 You are correct!

Comment: Yes :) your json array will be data. You can call it people instead and try your loop

Comment: The question was moved to chat