# How to catch JSON data in a HTML file and dynamically populate dropdown list?

Tags: python, html, bottle

I have created a small web service which has the ability of creating json data when certain URls are called. I have now created a HTML file which has a form and I want to populate a dropdown list from the JSON data I receive from one of the requests I have mentioned earlier. I am feeling lost in how to complete this task, please can someone help me out with this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532791/fill-dropdown-list-with-json

this might be a help

Comment: post more code, what you tried

Comment: I think this is more about JS not Python.